# How to make Rails 3.1 use SASS (Over SCSS) as the default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Having a hard time figuring out how to make SASS, not SCSS, as the default for stylesheets.

I've tried making a `sass_config.rb` file with this:

```
Sass::Plugin.options[:syntax] = :sass
Sass::Plugin.options[:style] = :compressed
```

I've also tried adding that to the environment.rb file. Either way I get this error:

```
.../config/environment.rb:7:in `<top (required)>': 
  uninitialized constant Sass::Plugin (NameError)
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

For rails 3.1.rc4, you could set the config:

```
config.sass.preferred_syntax = :sass
```

in the `application.rb` file

Comment: If you do this, it won't deploy in production b/c the sass and :asset group isn't active for production environments. You'll get a sass method not found being thrown by your deploy script. Personally, I ended out having to work around that by changing my Gemfile, commenting out the "group :assets" part, so that sass-rails, coffee-rails, uglifier gems were loaded for all configurations, not just as part of the assets group, like so: 
    # group :assets do
      gem 'sass-rails', " ~> 3.1.0"
      gem 'coffee-rails', " ~> 3.1.0"
      gem 'uglifier'
    # end

Comment: I made this change but it's still using scss as the default according to `rails g scaffold --help`.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you just `rake assets:precompile` before pushing to production?

Answer (score 8):

I added the following to `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
config.sass.preferred_syntax = :sass
```

That did the trick.

Answer (score 7):

Do `require 'sass/plugin'` and make sure it's at the bottom after your `Application.initialize!` call.

Comment: Just figured this out, like 5 minutes ago. The other solution is to have that require in a `config/initializers/sass.rb` file.

Comment: Looking further into it, it seems that still doesn't set SASS as the default for stylesheet generation.

Comment: Ok, the real solution is to have this in your `application.rb` file: `config.generators.stylesheet_engine = :sass`

Comment: While this fixes the issue of the error being thrown, I still can't seem to set the 'style' option so that it carries through to the generated stylesheet - The style line in the question worked for me in 3.0.7, but not now in 3.1. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I definitely prefer sass to scss too - have you considered just using the [compass gem](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass) for all your CSS, and adding `preferred_syntax = :sass` to config/compass.rb

I haven't tested this out yet on rails 3.1 yet but it works in 3.0.7

EDIT

As a troubleshooting step, what happens when you remove just the first line of code from sass_config.rb so that it just has the second one? Do both these lines cause the error?

Comment: I'd rather not use `compass` if I can, I was hoping 3.1 would solve the need to use Compass.

Comment: Same thing happens if I remove the first line. THe error is based on if `Sass::Plugin`.

Answer (score 2):

As @krainboltgreene commented, adding the following line to `config/application.rb`

```
config.generators.stylesheet_engine = :sass
```

makes `sass` the default format for stylesheet generators. However, since Rails 3.1.beta1 doesn't support it, one gets the following error messages

```
$ rails g scaffold user name:string
...
Could not find "scaffold.css.sass" in any of your source paths. Your current source paths are:
.../gems/railties-3.1.0.beta1/lib/rails/generators/rails/scaffold/templates
...

$ rails g controller users
...
Could not find "stylesheet.css.sass" in any of your source paths. Your current source paths are: 
.../gems/railties-3.1.0.beta1/lib/rails/generators/rails/assets/templates
```

As you see, one cannot change the default format without breaking the generators. Instead, you can manually create extra *.css.sass files, which are working fine with or without scss ones.

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer somewhere else, can't remember exactly, but put this in `config/initializers/sass.rb`:

```
Sass::Engine::DEFAULT_OPTIONS[:load_paths].tap do |load_paths|
  load_paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/stylesheets"
  load_paths << "#{Gem.loaded_specs['compass'].full_gem_path}/frameworks/compass/stylesheets"
end
```

I also prefer SASS syntax (to SCSS). All you have to do is name files `mystylesheet.css.sass` instead and it just works. You can even rename your `application.css` to `application.css.sass`, change the comments at the top to `//` instead of `/* */` and use the `require_*` directives—it all works, and then you can use SASS in your application global stylesheet. It won't if you use compass in `app/stylesheets`.

Don't require the `Sass::Plugin`, it's totally separate to the new Rails asset engine which is based on Sprockets. It already knows how to compile SASS for you and manages the bundling of assets properly.

I imagine a new Compass release will do this automatically for Rails 3.1+ projects using the asset pipeline.