# Set stylesheet_engine to sass in rails 3.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I'd like to use SASS as my default stylesheet engine instead of SCSS.  In my `Gemfile` I have

```
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
```

I also have

```
config.generators.stylesheet_engine = :sass
```

in my `config/application.rb`.  However, when I run `rails g scaffold --help`, it says

```
-se, [--stylesheet-engine=STYLESHEET_ENGINE]  # Engine for Stylesheets
                                              # Default: scss
```

So it still seems to think that scss is the default.

Do I have to do something else to use SASS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my understanding `sass-rails` will automatically use the sass syntax if you use the `.sass` extension.

**Edit:** To set the default syntax for the generator you will need to add

```
config.sass.preferred_syntax = :sass
```

to `config/application.rb`

Reference: [How to make Rails 3.1 use SASS (Over SCSS) as the default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006360/how-to-make-rails-3-1-use-sass-over-scss-as-the-default)

Comment: Probably, but when I use `rails g` I want it to create a sass file, not an scss file