# Rails Sass extension for indented sass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

Rails comes with SASS included, but generated files come with .scss extension. I want to use indented version of SASS. Should I just rename .scss extension to .sass and that will do the trick? or should I do some extra dances to make it work?

Comment: You didn't specify the version of Rails you are using but.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006360/how-to-make-rails-3-1-use-sass-over-scss-as-the-default

Comment: I'm using version 4.2